# root scope exception handler in browser when bindind json respone array in angular js 1.5.8

Tags: .net, angularjs, model-view-controller

[image]

[image]

response coming but when binding in scope this line throw an error in browser root scope exception

//////get tax

```
$scope.BindTax = function () {
    debugger;`enter code here`
    $http({
        url: 'Bindtaxdetails',
        method: "GET",
        datatype: 'json',

    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.lst_taxdetails = response.data;
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please share view file? when you use lst_taxdetails in view file?

Answer (score 0):

### Troubleshooting the $http Service

To log any error messages, add a `.catch` handler:

```
$scope.BindTax = function () {
    debugger;`enter code here`
    $http({
        url: 'Bindtaxdetails',
        method: "GET",
        ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶t̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶'̶j̶s̶o̶n̶'̶,̶

    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.lst_taxdetails = response.data;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        console.log(errorResponse.status);
        console.log(errorResponse);
        throw errorResponse;
    });
}
```

The `dataType` property is part of the jQuery AJAX library and not a propery of the $http service config. For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

You will get better error messages by using the `angular.js` library instead of `angular.min.js`.